# How to plot the feasible solution region of system of inequalities?

Tags: plotting

I have three inequalities that are below

$3x-4y\leq 12,$

$3x+2y\geq 6,$

$x+2y\leq 10,$

$x\geq 0$

$ y \geq 0$

I know how to plot linear equation in mathematica. The feasible solution region of these inequalities has been plot in figure in book as, I am interseted to plot the feasible solution of the region as plotted in book using mathematica. How can I plot and indicates each and everything shown in Figure.
[image]

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags. None of the tags you used is related in any way to the question. Look up `RegionPlot` and `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
constraints = {3 x - 4 y <= 12, 3 x + 2 y >= 6, x + 2 y <= 10, x >= 0, y >= 0};

ticklabels = {x, y} /. Solve[And[Or @@ eqs[[{1, 2, 3}]], 
       DeleteCases[{x, y}, #] == 0], {x, y}] & /@ {x, y};

tickf = {#, Framed[Style[#, 16] &@Row[{"(", #2, ",", #3, ")"}], 
     FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White]} &;

xticks = tickf[#, ##] & @@@ ticklabels[[1]];
yticks = tickf[#2, ##] & @@@ ticklabels[[2]];

Show[RegionPlot[And @@ constraints, {x, -8, 15}, {y, -5, 12},
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> LightRed, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"feasible"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20]],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[Equal @@@ constraints[[;; -3]]], {x, -8, 15}, {y, -5, 12}, 
   ContourStyle -> (Arrowheads[{{-.04, 0}, {.04, 1}, {.7, .85, 
      Graphics@ Text[Style[#, 14], {0, 0}, 
       {0, 1.5  (#[[1, 2]] /. {10 -> 1, 12 | 6 -> -1})},
       {(#[[1, 2]] /. {10 | 6 -> -1, 12 -> 1}), 0}]}}] & /@ 
         (HoldForm /@ constraints[[;; 3]])),
   MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10], BaseStyle -> Thick,
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[97, Equal @@@ constraints]] /. Line -> Arrow, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
 Ticks -> {xticks, yticks},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black, FontSize -> Medium],
 AxesStyle -> (Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[{-.04, .04}], ColorData[97]@#] & /@ {4, 5}), 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we show the corner points brother also as shown in figure which I have added?

Comment: @Noor, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks brother but not running in my system, do not know why?

Comment: Does Mathematics have tools for working with systems of linear inequalities of higher dimensions?

Answer (score 6):

As @Szabolcs suggested, you can use `RegionPlot` (for the region) and `ContourPlot` for the boundarylines,

```
plot1 = ContourPlot[{3 x - 4 y == 12, 3 x + 2 y == 6, x + 2 y == 10},
                    {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Axes -> True]
plot2 = RegionPlot[{3 x - 4 y <= 12 && 3 x + 2 y >= 6 && x + 2 y <= 10 && 
                    x >= 0 && y >= 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Axes -> True]
Show[plot1,plot2] (*to combine them*)
```

[image]

You can get the corner points by solving the equations. For example

```
Solve[3 x - 4 y == 12 && 3 x + 2 y == 6, {x, y}]
```

> {{x->8/3,y->-1}}

gives the intercepts between blue and orange line. Similarly you can get the intercepts of a line and axis and combine the points with `ListPlot`.

Comment: What to do to show the corner points?

Comment: Does Mathematics have tools for working with systems of linear inequalities of higher dimensions?